# Splitting complex urls data and get into an array by php

Tags: php, http, http-post

I have and url and this url contains 2 types of data.I want to set the corresponding data as key and value in an array.

### My link is

```
www.website.com/?get_id=1,2&get_num=23,54
```

Now I want get_id as key and get_num as value like this in php

```
array(
   [1] => 23,
   [2] => 54
)
```

How I can achieve that?

```
$id = $_GET['get_id'];
$num = $_GET['get_num'];
```

What to do next?

Comment: After $_GET, see how to use the explode function. More info: http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_explode.asp

Answer (score 0):

just do

```
$array = array_combine(explode(',',trim($_POST['get_id'])),
                       explode(',',trim($_POST['get_num']))
                      );
var_export($array);
```

explode - splits the string by comma to an array

array_combine  - creates from $keys and $values an array

trim - removes spaces around the number if any

work's only if both have same number count!!!